# qt how to listen unix domain socket in server

Tags: c++, qt, unix, dns, listen

QT how to listen a unix domain socket in server?

use QLocalServer to listen, code as follows, but the callback onNewConnection not called

demo code as follows:

```
mServer = new QLocalServer;

connect(mServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Have you read [the `QLocalServer` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html) (or any other reference or tutorial)? Because it seems you have missed a few bits. And if you haven't missed to *listen* for new connections you need to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: unix domain socket must point to point. now I receive data, but it's a auth msg like this    Read Data From Client: "\x00""AUTH EXTERNAL 31303030\r\n"

Comment: The actual protocol of the messages being transmitted depends on the server and client, and if you need help with that you need to ask a new question with more specifics.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, and as already mentioned, please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: [ com.belmoussaoui.Decoder ~]$ dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.Hello
onNewConnection called, server:  "/run/user/1000/.dbus-proxy/session-bus-proxy-ZIO6F1"
Read Data From Client: "\x00""AUTH EXTERNAL 31303030\r\n"
^ConDisconnected called sender: QLocalSocket(0x19c0b30)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.